# Number of paths of length three in $K_4$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> How many paths of length $3$ can be made from $K_4$ where $4$ represents the number of vertices?

I believe the answer is $12$ just by counting the number of different combinations of paths with length $2$. I don't know how to relate this to combinations though. I was thinking $4 \choose 3$ determines the number of ways $4$ vertices can be chosen for a path of length $3$ to be out together, but I think I'm missing something conceptually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'm going to presume that by *path*, you want to exclude *loops*. Thinking of the problem this way, when we are counting paths of length three, we can think of this as counting the number of orders in which can  traverse the four vertices. That is, we are picking the number of ways to *permute* the vertices. So I believe the answer to your question is $_4P_4 = 4! = 24$ different paths of length three.

Maybe, though, some paths are the same as others? Naming the vertices $1,2,3,4$, do you want to consider the paths $1\to2\to3\to4$ and $4\to3\to2\to1$ to be the same? If so, then you can just divide the answer from before by two and get a total of $12$ distinct paths.

Comment: Thanks so much ! This makes sense.